# How to transfer skeleton weights in vertex shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, collada, skeletal-mesh

I made a c++ collada reader but i draw a 3K animated mesh in 4ms using the opengl direct mode . That's too slow.

So i decided to use a vertex shader .In a skeleton , each vertex have a weight (zero or more) for each bone.
For a 3K mesh with 40 bones, you have 120 000 weights for the whole object.

The only problem is in GLSL you can't declare uniform arrays with big sizes.

For example this will compile ( vertex shader):

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
uniform float weights [10] ;

void main (void)

{
 float test= weights[0];

  gl_Position = ftransform();

}
```

/// but not this :

```
uniform float weights [120000] ;

void main (void)

{
  float test= weights[0];

  gl_Position = ftransform();

}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////

I have seen in some pages i could use glVertexAttribPointer() to set attributes for each vertex. This will be done if i had  between 1 and 4 bones (i could use vecX attributes), but GLSL( in my case 1.20) don't
accecpt attributes arrays.

Comment: Err.. Weights are vertex attributes. Bone matrices are uniforms.

Comment: how do you pass a 40 float attribute to the vertex shader?

Comment: There is no need for such big amount. You set all bone matrices as uniforms and pass one vec4 as bone influences and one vec4i with indices of influencing bones. Just two extra attributes per vertex to handle up to four influencing bones per vertex; or four attributes for 8 bones in some extreme cases, but it is very rarely needed.

Comment: Jeebus, that is a ridiculously large number of uniforms. You should use a buffer texture for that. Also, consider packing any array of scalar uniforms into into something like `vec4` or `mat4`s because some implementations have difficulty storing scalar uniforms - `float` uniforms have the same storage requirements as `vec4` on some older GPUs (particularly the ones with purely vector ALUs).

Comment: Regarding "vertex attribute arrays", a `mat4` vertex attribute is for all intents and purposes an array of 4 `vec4` attributes. It takes up 4 sequential vertex attribute slots (and as such, also requires 4 separate vertex attribute pointers).

Comment: Yes if i dont have another issue i will use a mat4 and store the weights and indices in. for example

0.2   2   0.6   4

1.0   3   0.38  2

0.4   4   0.55  15

1.0   5   1.0   6

But i have to consider each vertex is max controlled by 8 bones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned by  keltar  and Andon M. Coleman , you should use vec4 attributes.
In some cases some vertices have more than 4 bones controling them. What you could do is just consider the  bones with the bigest weights.